# Bootstrap Collapsing menu showing all in default

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I am trying to create a collapsing menu, however all of my menu shows on default. It does not collapse or give the option to click/close.  Here is the code I am using for the menu (there are 3 questions)

Here is the gist for the entire page- https://gist.github.com/d01cbfefac2c62ed9eb1

```
<div class="header">
  <h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multislectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a role "button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"><span class= "glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></span>
            Why did you become a developer?
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          I became a web developer to gain a unique perspective on education reform. I believe that the only way to have reform in education is if students are ready for future jobs and what made sense to me was having students who understood computer languages. This means that I have to learn to code in order to teach how to code.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a lot of attention mistakes: [instruction](http://prntscr.com/7z7sz7), [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c2aszw8h/1/)

1). html tags aren't closed right - no outer div, body, html are closed.
2). div class="panel-group" id="accordion" should be only put only once - it's a wrapper for accordion.

3). data-parent="#accordion" not data-parent="#accordian"

4). on the panels that you want to hide on the first show - remove class "in " and put class "collapsed" on the link of the panel

```
 <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour"><span class= "glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></span> How do you do it all, and with such great hair!? </a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

5). http://prntscr.com/7z7vtm